# How does geckodriver work with Firefox?

Tags: selenium, firefox, webdriver, geckodriver

[Geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) is used to control Firefox. And I have a question is that what is the way it communicates with FF? Are there some JavaScript codes injected to every websites to move mouse, catch event,.. Or FF has some APIs to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The Webdriver hooks into the actual application code via specific hooks. So no JavaScript or other plugins. Keep in. Mind that the Webdriver is maintained by the Mozilla team.

Comment: Do you know where to find document about these?